# Getting an Exception / ANR with greenDAO

Tags: android, sqlite, dao, greendao

I have a huge problem! Some people that are using my app are getting an ANR (app is not responding), when they are doing a database operation (like updating an Object to the database), while an (intent-)service with database reading is running.

**In detail:**

I am using a single-instance pattern with the Application-Desgin. That means the given context to the SQLiteOpenHelper is the ApplicationContext
the block operations are:

```
ArrayList<Workposition> web_list = (ArrayList<Workposition>) sessionDAO
                    .getWorkpositionDao().queryBuilder().list();
```

AND

```
sessionDAO.getWorkpositionDao().update(plantevent);
```

The both sessionDao using the a SQLLiteHelper with the ApplicationContext. The first read operation is happening in the background and the second operation happens at an onClick method

if you are interested in reading the ANR there you go, but the most important stuff is listed above.
The code lines mentioned above are in EventView and in Workposition.

```
    ----- pid 23262 at 2014-10-21 07:58:59 -----
Cmd line: de.myApp

JNI: CheckJNI is off; workarounds are off; pins=0; globals=293

DALVIK THREADS:
(mutexes: tll=0 tsl=0 tscl=0 ghl=0)

"main" prio=5 tid=1 WAIT
| group="main" sCount=1 dsCount=0 obj=0x41806ea0 self=0x416fcb78
| sysTid=23262 nice=0 sched=0/0 cgrp=apps handle=1073869140
| state=S schedstat=( 0 0 0 ) utm=306 stm=55 core=1
at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
- waiting on <0x41806f70> (a java.lang.VMThread) held by tid=1 (main)
at java.lang.Thread.parkFor(Thread.java:1205)
at sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Unsafe.java:325)
at java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.park(LockSupport.java:157)
at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.parkAndCheckInterrupt(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:813)
at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.acquireQueued(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:846)
at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.acquire(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:1175)
at java.util.concurrent.locks.ReentrantLock$NonfairSync.lock(ReentrantLock.java:180)
at java.util.concurrent.locks.ReentrantLock.lock(ReentrantLock.java:256)
at de.greenrobot.dao.identityscope.IdentityScopeLong.put2(IdentityScopeLong.java:85)
at de.greenrobot.dao.identityscope.IdentityScopeLong.put(IdentityScopeLong.java:76)
at de.greenrobot.dao.identityscope.IdentityScopeLong.put(IdentityScopeLong.java:31)
at de.greenrobot.dao.AbstractDao.attachEntity(AbstractDao.java:695)
at de.greenrobot.dao.AbstractDao.updateInsideSynchronized(AbstractDao.java:680)
at de.greenrobot.dao.AbstractDao.update(AbstractDao.java:654)
at de.myApp.views.EventView$1.run(EventView.java:122)
at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:157)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5356)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1265)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1081)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)

"IntentService[a]" prio=5 tid=13 TIMED_WAIT
| group="main" sCount=1 dsCount=0 obj=0x42e28460 self=0x7b5302c0
| sysTid=23337 nice=0 sched=0/0 cgrp=apps handle=2005620856
| state=S schedstat=( 0 0 0 ) utm=7309 stm=180 core=0
at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
- waiting on <0x42c4b8f8> (a java.lang.VMThread) held by tid=13 (IntentService[a])
at java.lang.Thread.parkFor(Thread.java:1205)
at sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Unsafe.java:325)
at java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.parkNanos(LockSupport.java:197)
at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnectionPool.waitForConnection(SQLiteConnectionPool.java:739)
at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnectionPool.acquireConnection(SQLiteConnectionPool.java:400)
at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteSession.acquireConnection(SQLiteSession.java:905)
at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteSession.executeForCursorWindow(SQLiteSession.java:834)
at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteQuery.fillWindow(SQLiteQuery.java:62)
at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCursor.fillWindow(SQLiteCursor.java:152)
at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCursor.onMove(SQLiteCursor.java:124)
at android.database.AbstractCursor.moveToPosition(AbstractCursor.java:214)
at android.database.AbstractCursor.moveToNext(AbstractCursor.java:245)
at de.greenrobot.dao.AbstractDao.loadAllFromCursor(AbstractDao.java:392)
at de.greenrobot.dao.AbstractDao.loadAllAndCloseCursor(AbstractDao.java:184)
at de.greenrobot.dao.InternalQueryDaoAccess.loadAllAndCloseCursor(InternalQueryDaoAccess.java:21)
at de.greenrobot.dao.query.Query.list(Query.java:121)
at de.greenrobot.dao.query.QueryBuilder.list(QueryBuilder.java:374)
at de.myApp.modelDAO.Workposition.upload(Workposition.java:588)
at de.myApp.service.ApiService.update(ApiService.java:138)
at de.myApp.service.ApiService.onHandleIntent(ApiService.java:51)
at android.app.IntentService$ServiceHandler.handleMessage(IntentService.java:65)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:157)
at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:61)

"Binder_3" prio=5 tid=11 NATIVE
| group="main" sCount=1 dsCount=0 obj=0x42fc7e68 self=0x778c0300
| sysTid=23306 nice=0 sched=0/0 cgrp=apps handle=2006715504
| state=S schedstat=( 0 0 0 ) utm=0 stm=0 core=1
#00 pc 0002072c /system/lib/libc.so (__ioctl+8)
#01 pc 0002cec3 /system/lib/libc.so (ioctl+14)
#02 pc 0001d3ed /system/lib/libbinder.so (android::IPCThreadState::talkWithDriver(bool)+140)
#03 pc 0001daf7 /system/lib/libbinder.so (android::IPCThreadState::getAndExecuteCommand()+6)
#04 pc 0001db8d /system/lib/libbinder.so (android::IPCThreadState::joinThreadPool(bool)+48)
#05 pc 000219e9 /system/lib/libbinder.so
#06 pc 0000ea5d /system/lib/libutils.so (android::Thread::_threadLoop(void*)+216)
#07 pc 00052299 /system/lib/libandroid_runtime.so (android::AndroidRuntime::javaThreadShell(void*)+68)
#08 pc 0000e58f /system/lib/libutils.so
#09 pc 0000d278 /system/lib/libc.so (__thread_entry+72)
#10 pc 0000d410 /system/lib/libc.so (pthread_create+240)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.run(Native Method)

"AsyncTask #1" prio=5 tid=10 WAIT
| group="main" sCount=1 dsCount=0 obj=0x42e06f38 self=0x778c2768
| sysTid=23301 nice=10 sched=0/0 cgrp=apps/bg_non_interactive handle=2005674944
| state=S schedstat=( 0 0 0 ) utm=29 stm=5 core=2
at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
- waiting on <0x42e070d0> (a java.lang.VMThread) held by tid=10 (AsyncTask #1)
at java.lang.Thread.parkFor(Thread.java:1205)
at sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Unsafe.java:325)
at java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.park(LockSupport.java:157)
at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.await(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:2017)
at java.util.concurrent.LinkedBlockingQueue.take(LinkedBlockingQueue.java:410)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.getTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1035)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1097)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)

"pool-1-thread-1" prio=5 tid=12 WAIT
| group="main" sCount=1 dsCount=0 obj=0x42ca18e0 self=0x79564280
| sysTid=23281 nice=0 sched=0/0 cgrp=apps handle=2035697368
| state=S schedstat=( 0 0 0 ) utm=1 stm=1 core=2
at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
- waiting on <0x42ca1a28> (a java.lang.VMThread) held by tid=12 (pool-1-thread-1)
at java.lang.Thread.parkFor(Thread.java:1205)
at sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Unsafe.java:325)
at java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.park(LockSupport.java:157)
at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.await(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:2017)
at java.util.concurrent.LinkedBlockingQueue.take(LinkedBlockingQueue.java:410)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.getTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1035)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1097)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)

"Binder_2" prio=5 tid=9 NATIVE
| group="main" sCount=1 dsCount=0 obj=0x42a3f878 self=0x7255dc60
| sysTid=23273 nice=0 sched=0/0 cgrp=apps handle=1918229016
| state=S schedstat=( 0 0 0 ) utm=0 stm=0 core=0
#00 pc 0002072c /system/lib/libc.so (__ioctl+8)
#01 pc 0002cec3 /system/lib/libc.so (ioctl+14)
#02 pc 0001d3ed /system/lib/libbinder.so (android::IPCThreadState::talkWithDriver(bool)+140)
#03 pc 0001daf7 /system/lib/libbinder.so (android::IPCThreadState::getAndExecuteCommand()+6)
#04 pc 0001db8d /system/lib/libbinder.so (android::IPCThreadState::joinThreadPool(bool)+48)
#05 pc 000219e9 /system/lib/libbinder.so
#06 pc 0000ea5d /system/lib/libutils.so (android::Thread::_threadLoop(void*)+216)
#07 pc 00052299 /system/lib/libandroid_runtime.so (android::AndroidRuntime::javaThreadShell(void*)+68)
#08 pc 0000e58f /system/lib/libutils.so
#09 pc 0000d278 /system/lib/libc.so (__thread_entry+72)
#10 pc 0000d410 /system/lib/libc.so (pthread_create+240)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.run(Native Method)
```

I have no idea why this problem apears. Is it because of the single-instance? would it work if i would use two different contexts? or should i execute update in an background thread?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should never access the database on the main thread. Lots of database operations use a single lock so when you do this, any long running background query can block your main thread. Since background tasks will have lower priority, it can easily cause an ANR. 
In addition to this, disk access may be slowed by any random reason (e.g. play store updating apps). You really don't want to rely your UI on that (don't forget, your UI has only 16 ms).

In this ANR, the background thread already has the Identity Scope lock, waiting to get an SqliteConnection while your main thread is blocked by the Identity Scope lock of Green Dao. Nothing shows why database is taking so much to provide the connection (are there any other threads not shown in the ANR?).

Just make sure you never access the database on main thread. (write or read, does not matter much). I believe system would eventually solve this conflict (e.g. a connection will eventually be available)

Comment: yeah you are right. Actually i know this, but i thought that greenDao woul take care of this. Do you know something about that? 

But i have to admit that greenDao does not take care of this. Perhaps its somehow a bug in the framework. It only happens on one device

Answer (score 1):

Run your app with [StrictMode](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/StrictMode.html) enabled to see where you're doing long-running operations on the UI thread then move those operations to an AsyncTask or something.

Comment: does it mean that "update()" waits until it can be executed, but the UI does let him wait some milliseconds?

Comment: Yes, blocking the UI thread for more than 5 seconds causes the ANR http://developer.android.com/training/articles/perf-anr.html